# Locking option for a 100mm quickrelease?

Tags: electric-bike, quick-release, security

I recently got a [Ride1Up LMT'D](https://ride1up.com/product/lmtd-2/), and it came with a quick release for the front wheel. According to their support, it's 100mm wide, and I can't seem to find a 100mm pinhead or similar product :( Any ideas what I can do to secure the front wheel, without having to carry an additional lock everywhere?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Do one of these questions/answers answer your question? There appears to be both Pinhead and Pitlock brands of locking QR skewers. https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4762/theft-deterrents-in-addition-to-locking-up-a-bike   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30773/security-wheel-skewers-for-front-facing-horizontal-dropouts

Comment: 100mm is the standard OLD size for front wheels.  99% of bikes will be this size, keep looking.

Comment: Pinhead are probably just measuring in an odd way. They definitely do skewers for front wheels because I've got 2. I have had trouble with their sizing at the back when I needed a longer than normal skewer, but the next length up didn't have enough thread to do up tight. I solved that by cutting a few turns more thread, potentially an option for you if you need something a little shorter than one of their lengths